# Firestore use equaly filter and superior filter on OrderBy

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a **Firestore** query to get all my incoming meetings. Some meetings have a `date`, and some don't (they will be scheduled later). Here's my current query:

```
query(
  collection,
  orderBy('date'),
  or(where('date', '==', null), where('date', '>=', new Date()))
);
```

However, when I run this query, I get the error:

> Order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter date

I understand this error in certain cases, but I have an `OR` condition that is supposed to handle both cases.

To provide some additional context, I'm using **Cloud Firestore** and a front-end client to query the database. I've tried using different approaches and queries, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I've also checked the **Firestore documentation** and other resources for help, but I suspect this may be a bug.

If anyone has any ideas on how to order the results by date while still including meetings without a date, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the two, like so:

```
const getScheduledWithoutDate = query(
  collection,
  where('date', '==', null),
);

const getScheduledWithDate = query(
  collection,
  where('date', '!==', null), 
  where('date', '>=', new Date()))
);
```

Be careful, the syntax is not correct, I'm on typescript and just want to get the point in, then sort them locally.

Comment: I've considered that solution, but unfortunately, it won't work for me because I need to implement pagination in my query.

Comment: I would still sort it locally but yeah firebase is very broken in the query department

Answer (score 0):

From the list of [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) in the Firestore documentation:

> You can't order your query by a field included in an equality (`==`) or `in` clause.

I'm actually not sure why this limitation exists, so I'm gonna ask around - but it doesn't seem to be a bug as you expect.

---

Would it be possible to rewrite the query to use `!=` instead of `==`?

```
query(
  collection,
  orderBy('date'),
  where('date', '!=', null), 
  where('date', '>=', new Date())
);
```

And in fact, it might already work with just that last condition as `null` is not an actual date value:

```
query(
  collection,
  orderBy('date'),
  where('date', '>=', new Date())
);
```

Comment: The != condition is working, but it's not producing the desired result. However, when I try using >= directly, I'm not receiving the expected null values in the result.

Comment: Oh right, that would exclude the `null` values indeed. In that case I'm actually not sure if your use-case can currently be met with a single query. You might be left with the approach that Wayne suggested, despite its downsides.